# Is it better to wear a flat counterforce brace or a non-flat one to treat an lateral or medial epicondylopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis

I wonder whether it is better to wear a flat counterforce brace or a non-flat one to treat an lateral or medial epicondylopathy.

By non-flat, I mean it has a bump, as illustrated below (image taken from [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00QY0EFJM/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QY0EFJM)):

[image]

Example of flat counterforce brace:

[image]

[image]

Example of non-flat counterforce brace:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.